# Flasgger Swagger UI not loading endpoints

Tags: rest, flask, yaml, swagger-ui, flasgger

I want to use Flasgger to read my openapi definitions from a `swagger.yml` file.

My swagger.yml file:

```
# swagger.yml

openapi: 3.0.0
info:
  title: "Job DB Flask EST API"
  description: "An API about opportunities and applications"
  version: "1.0.0"

paths:
  /companies:
    get:
      operationId: "companies.read_all"
      tags:
        - Companies
      summary: "Read the list of companies"
      responses:
        200:
          description: "Successfully read companies list"
    post:
      operationId: "companies.create"
      tags:
        - Companies
      summary: "Create a Company"
      requestBody:
        description: "Company to create"
        required: True
        content:
          application/json:
            schema:
              x-body-name: "company"
              $ref: "#/components/schemas/Company"
      responses:
        201:
          description: "Successfully created company"
  /companies/{Id}:
    get:
      operationId: "companies.read_one"
      tags:
        - Companies
      summary: "Read one company"
      parameters:
        - $ref: "#/components/parameters/id"
      responses:
        200:
          description: "Successfully read company"
    put:
      operationId: "companies.update"
      tags:
        - Companies
      summary: "Update a company"
      parameters:
        - $ref: "#/components/parameters/id"
      responses:
        200:
          description: "Successfully updated company"
      requestBody:
        content:
          application/json:
            schema:
              x-body-name: "company"
              $ref: "#/components/schemas/Company"
    delete:
      operationId: "companies.delete"
      tags:
        - Companies
      summary: "Delete a company"
      parameters:
        - $ref: "#/components/parameters/id"
      responses:
        204:
          description: "Successfully deleted company"

components:
  parameters:
    id:
      name: "Id"
      description: "Guid Identifier"
      in: path
      required: True
      schema:
        type: "string"
        format: uuid
  schemas:
    CompanyStatus:
      required:
        - Id
      properties:
        Id:
          type: "string"
          format: uuid
        Description:
          type: "string"
    Company:
      type: "object"
      required:
        - Id
      properties:
        Id:
          type: "string"
          format: uuid
        Name:
          type: "string"
        Description:
          type: "string"
        CompanyStatusId:
          type: "string"
          format: uuid
    Opportunity:
      required:
        - Id
      properties:
        Id:
          type: "string"
          format: uuid
        CompanyId:
          type: "string"
          format: uuid
        Title:
          type: "string"
        Url:
          type: "string"
        Content:
          type: "string"
        Notes:
          type: "string"
    ApplicationMethod:
      required:
        - Id
      properties:
        Id:
          type: "string"
          format: uuid
        Description:
          type: "string"
    ApplicationStatus:
      required:
        - Id
      properties:
        Id:
          type: "string"
          format: uuid
        Description:
          type: "string"
    Application:
      required:
        - Id
      properties:
        Id:
          type: "string"
          format: uuid
        Submitted:
          type: "string"
          format: date-time
        OpportunityId:
          type: "string"
          format: uuid
        ApplicationStatusId:
          type: "string"
          format: uuid
        ApplicationMethodId:
          type: "string"
          format: uuid
        Updated:
          type: "string"
          format: "date-time"
```

My **init**.py file:

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request

from .config import Config
from .extensions import db, swagger
from flasgger import Swagger, swag_from

from .models import Company


def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(Config)

    db.init_app(app)
    swagger.init_app(app)

    @app.route('/companies', methods=['GET'])
    @swag_from('swagger.yml', validation=True)
    def companies_read_all():
        """
        Read the list of my companies
        :return: The list of companies
        """
        companies = db.session.query(Company).all()
        return jsonify([company.serialize() for company in companies])
    return app
```

When I call `flask run` and navigate to the Swagger UI (localhost/apidocs/) the UI loads but when I go to expand the endpoint the loading animation appears and stays there. No console messages or errors get printed out.

I've tried looking for documentation around the `@app.route` and `swag_from` lines. I've tried enabling validation as well. I get the feeling I'm missing something simple.

[Swagger UI Screencap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E82Vb.png)